# What is the next letter in this series (zxcvb...)?

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

What is the next letter in this series?

Z X C V B ...

Comment: Didn't this get asked once already?

Comment: next letter must be N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last alphabetical row of QWERTY keyboard

> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> ...........

[image]

Comment: For completeness we should mention that this must be a "qwerty" keyboard. Other keyboard arrangements are available including several Dvorak variations and also the French (?) "azerty" keyboard (think there's also a "qwertz").

Comment: @IanF1, okay, I will update my answer.

Comment: @IanF1 you are right the Germans have the Y and Z swapped on a regular qwerty keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It is

> N. That's the next character on the lower row on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

> N
>
> Look at your QWERTY keyboard.